# UWP OneDrive appfolder troubles

Tags: c#, onedrive

Win10 c# uwp using Microsoft.OneDriveSDK - cannot get approot childrens, cannot upload items.

```
private readonly string[] scopes = new string[] { "onedrive.appfolder", "wl.offline_access", "wl.signin" };
IOneDriveClient oneDriveClient = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes);
await oneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
...
var items = await oneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Request().GetAsync();
Or
var items = await oneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Children.Request().GetAsync();
```

Exception "OneDriveException" is throwed - Code: "notAllowed", Message: "Max limit on number of Items is reached".
Same exception if trying to upload new file.
App is associated with store.
What do I wrong?

Comment: SOLVED! - Just deleted the app folder in onedrive and no more exceptions :)

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that you were unable to perform a GET when it was in this state? How many children were there in the approot?

Comment: Approot was empty. I think i know why was a problem. This small personal project was started few months ago as android app, was made some tests with onedrive and development stopped. Now priority is given to windows. To access onedrive, uwp app must be associated with store. This procedure creates new appid, while the folder on onedrive was created using old appid from android (but forgotten). Same folder name but different owners caused problems. So, when folder was deleted and recreated by uwp app, problems gone. This is just my opinion.